# Ubuntu doesn't use external drive properly

Tags: hard-drive, external-hdd, 20.10

I have the following problem with using an external drive on Ubuntu: copying starts with the maximum of 300mb/s speed (I have only one USB port, and it's USB 3.1), after ~10sec speed is nearly half of it (150mb/s), and so on. After several minutes it can be nearly 10mb/s no matter what files I'm copying (20 videos of ~2GB size or back upping my Documents folder with many small files). It's extremely annoying! Windows works well with it.

In addition, stopping copying (in Nautilus) results in damage to the filesystem in the external drive and I have to restore it in Windows.

Several important notes: I have this problem in multiple Linux distributions, in 2 laptops and 3 external drives. So, why this problem persists?

Edit 1: My external drives use NTFS and my laptop has 16GB of RAM, 1TB SSD. There is a lot of free space left on SSD (hundreds of GB). Compression is not enabled. There's a process `/sbin/mount.ntfs` using only 45% of my CPU according to `htop`. Ubuntu 20.10.

Edit 2: Tried to change NTFS to exFAT. Same behaviour.

Comment: What is the filesystem on the external drive? How much memory does your system have?

Comment: My external drives use NTFS and my laptop has 16gb of RAM, 1tb SSD. There is a lot of free space left on SSD (hundreds of gb).

Comment: Is there NTFS compression on the external drive? Is there an Ubuntu process that starts using nearly 100% CPU during this write operation? Please add all this information in your original post by [edit]ing it.

Comment: You have not said what version of Ubuntu this is.

Comment: why not use fat32? that is what ubuntu is expecting...

Comment: @David it is 20.10

Comment: why not use fat32 or ext4? that is what ubuntu is expecting...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that usage of NTFS and exFAT on Linux is quite slow. Formatting to ext4 solved the problem, and in my case, I found the possibility to do all necessary backups from my dual boot using only Linux (NTFS works fast enough in my NVMe).
For me, this behavior seemed so strange that I wrote this question, but it looks like a common performance problem on Linux of these filesystems.

Comment: Yea ntfs is windows only.

Comment: Did you have to use DISKPART or were you able to do it via file explorer? Might be worth adding your method of overwriting to the answer: those who see this page in the future will likely be searching for the same fix.